# servlet is not working (also has null pointer error) , servlet couldn't get the value from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tomcat, servlets

I couldn't  find a reason why servlet is not working here.

So, in html, i have a select country field, empty first. Once i click the drop down menu to choose nothing, and then click anywhere else, it should show the error message(Please choose a country) next to the field.

html:

```
<select id="select-country" name = "select-country/region" onblur="validateCountry()">
                        <option value = "" selected = "selected">Select One</option>
                        <option value ="AU">Australia</option>
                        <option value ="BA">Bahamas</option>
                        <option value ="CN">China</option>
                        <option value ="DK">Denmark</option>
                        <option value ="US">United States</option>        
                    </select>                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <span id = "countryError"></span>
```

javascript:

```
var req;
var f;
var t;

    function validateCountry()
    {
        t = document.getElementById("select-country");
        f = document.getElementById("countryError");
        alert ("start here" + t.value);
        var url = "http://localhost:8080/ibmProject/servlet?select-country=" + t.value();
        alert ("Hi,here is inside validateCountry");
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("GET", url, true);
        req.onreadystatechange = callback;
        req.send(null);     
    }
    function callback()
    {
        alert ("Hi,here is inside countryValidation");
        if (req.readyState === 4 && req.status === 200)
        {
            var return_data = req.responseText;
            alert("callback: " + return_data);
            f.innerHTML = return_data;
            f.style.color = "#FF0000";
            t.focus();   
        }
    }
```

servlet:

In servlet, if i don't add `if(c!=null)` condition, it gives the null pointer error. I tried to type http://localhost:8080/ibmProject/servlet in the browser to test if servlet is working or not. Same thing, if i don't add `if(c!=null)`, it gives HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NullPointerException.

However, no matter what i choose in the country field, the string c in servlet is always null. 
Also, even if the string c is null, then,  `out.print("*testing!*")` should be returned to `var return_data = req.responseText` (in javascript), but it didn't. There is no error message :"testing" next to country field.

I checked the apache folder,

> C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.68\work\Catalina\localhost/ibmProject

it is empty, does it suppose to have some files?

I realized that `alert ("Hi,here is inside validateCountry")`; (javascript) never executes.
So, i guess the problem is about 
`var url = "http://localhost:8080/ibmProject/servlet?select-country=" + t.value();` (in javascript)
this line. 
The servlet.java is located here.
NetBeansProjects\ibmProject\src\java

The html, javascript, css are all here:
\NetBeansProjects\ibmProject\web

```
public class servlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
        //response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String c = request.getParameter("select-country");
        if(c!=null)
        {
            System.out.println("Finally!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!------------------------------------"+c);
            if (c.equals(""))
            {
                out.print("*Please select a country!*");
            }  
            else 
            {
                out.print("");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            out.print("*testing...!*");
        }
    }
```

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCfVt.png)

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

Can someone help?
Really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `onblur` handler is never called: Have you checked its availability, e.g. with Firebug or your browser's developer tools? Just execute it willingly through a temporary button and keep the console in sight - it might be a simple typo somewhere. Also, I don't quite understand how your `validateCountry()` is never called (or the alert in there), but you still run into problems with the servlet.

Speaking of the servlet: How did you come up with implementing your logic in `processRequest()`?

Move it to `doGet()` or `service()` as suggested in [`HttpServlet's` javadoc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html). There it'll be in the proper place - and if the parameter is present in the request, it will be available. If you like, have a breakpoint there and inspect the request object for parameters to get a glimpse of what data you actually are getting.

Comment: Thanks, there is a simple typo.                                                                    var url = "http://localhost:8080/ibmProject/servlet?select-country=" + t.value();      --< here... should be just t.value